# GridView の列幅を固定する方法はありますか？

Tags: c#, asp.net

タイトルの件、tdのwidthを設定しても画面サイズを調整すると少し列の幅が変わってしまいます。
固定する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事をたどるとあるかもしれません。[GridViewで列幅を固定にする方法](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=43595&forum=7), [ＧｒｉｄＶｉｅｗで列の幅を変わらないようにする](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=6872&KLOG=17), [how to fix column width of gridview](https://forums.asp.net/t/1739285.aspx), [WPF GridViewColumnHeader fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26256922/9014308), [Prevent user from resizing columns with WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/181956/9014308), [How do I get my grid to do fixed width ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23476361/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

フォームのAutoSizeがNone以外になっていませんか？

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: この記事はasp.netではない気がします。